# How to write excluding specific strings in shell script

Tags: regex, shell

I would like to use shell script to remove the entire tag if it contains a specific string inside the <script> tag.

Example: If XXX is included in the <script> tag, delete the entire tag

- Before deletion　<script aaa>bbbccc</script><script ddd>eeeXXXfff</script><script ggg>hhhiii</script>
- After deletion　<script aaa>bbbccc</script><script ggg>hhhiii</script>

I got it done with the following command.

`sed -i 's/<script[^>]*>[^<]*XXX[^<]*<\/script>//g' test.txt`

But it doesn't work if XXX contains "<" before and after.

- undeliteable　<script aaa>bbbccc</script><script ddd>ee<eXXXf<ff</script><script ggg>hhhiii</script>

Can someone please tell me how to remove the middle <script> tag in the above case.

Thanks for your cooperation.

Answer (score 0):

Make the before/after parts of any length (including zero):

```
sed -i 's/<script[^>]*>[^<]*XXX[^<]*<\/script>//g' test.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

With your shown samples in GNU `awk` you could try following solution.

```
awk '
match($0,/(^.*)\<script [^>]*>[^X]*XXX[^/]*(\/.*)$/,arr){
  print arr[1] arr[2]
}
'  Input_file
```

If you are Happy with above's output then append  `> temp && mv temp Input_file` to solution to do a inplace save.